# Run Python Script from PHP on IIS Server

Tags: php, python

I've got IIS 8.5 installed, with PHP installed and running.  I've also added a handler mapping (with the %s %s at the end of the python.exe path) to the website. I can run the python script directly from the browser successfully (prints "Hello World").

This is all just configured on the Default Web Site for testing purposes.  When I attempt to set a PHP variable to the output of a python script, the variable does not appear to receive the value.  IUSR and IIS_IUSRS have modify permissions on the root directory (C:\inetpub\wwwroot), which is where all HTML, PHP and Python files are located.

My code is as follows:

PHP:

```
<?php
    $coutput = shell_exec("/test.py > ~debug.log 2>&1");
    include 'header.html';
    echo "</br>Python Output:</br>" . $coutput;
    var_dump($coutput);
    include 'footer.html';
?>
```

**NOTE:** I've also tried "**python** test.py > ~debug.log 2>&1" in the shell_exec function to no avail.

Python (blank print is to display properly in browser when run directly):

```
print("")
print("Hello World")
```

Initially, I thought this was a permissions issue with PHP, so I ran the python script from PHP via command line and get the python code:

c:\inetpub\wwwroot>"c:\program files\php\v7.3\php.exe" c:\inetpub\wwwroot\test.py

print("")
print("Hello World")

PHP is not in safe mode.

What am I missing?  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: When you encounter this kind of issues don't forget to use the absolute path of your script, and it seems that your python script is in total different location from the php one

Comment: Both scripts are in the same folder (wwwroot).  I tested script with absolute path (/test.py) with the same results.